# NestJS with Microsoft Azure Function v4 does not set response headers

Tags: azure-functions, nestjs

before question, sorry to I'm poor at English.

this is my `redirect.interceptor.ts`

```
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class RedirectInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const req: Request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const res: Response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();

    if (req.hostname === 'some.where.before') {
      const redirectUrl = req.url.replace('some.where.before', 'some.where.after');
      res.redirect(redirectUrl);
    }

    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

and it registered at `main.azure.ts` like:
`app.useGlobalInterceptors(new TimeoutInterceptor(), new RedirectInterceptor());`

but it does not redirect to 'some.where.after' but just display this:

<p>Found. Redirecting to <a href="https://some.where.after/v1/landing/ad/1?keyword=keyword">https://some.where.after/v1/landing/ad/1?keyword=keyword</a></p>

and `Location` do not exists at network tap. but statusCode is `302 Found`.

how to solve it? I've tried some ways but wasn't effective.

1. edit `proxies.json` and removed `redirect.interceptor.ts`

   ```
   {
     "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
     "proxies": {
       "redirect": {
         "matchCondition": {
           "route": "/v1/{*all}",
           "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"]
         },
         "responseOverrides": {
           "response.statusCode": "301",
           "response.headers.Location": "https://some.where.after/{all}"
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   it doesn't effective. even statusCode was 200.

Comment: Hope this reference [helps](https://github.com/nestjs/azure-func-http/issues/407)

Comment: great thanks to @Sampath

[this](https://github.com/nestjs/azure-func-http/issues/407) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Context, HttpRequest } from '@azure/functions';
import { AzureHttpAdapter } from '@nestjs/azure-func-http';
import { createApp } from '../src/main.azure';

function createPsuedoApp(createApp: () => Promise<any>): () => Promise<any> {
  return async (): Promise<any> => {
    const app = await createApp();
    const psuedoApp = {
      getHttpAdapter: () => {
        return {
          getInstance: () => {
            return (req: any, res: any) => {
              const done = req.context.done;
              req.context.done = (err?: string | Error, result?: any) => {
                res.writeHead();
                done(err, result);
              };
              app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance()(req, res);
            };
          },
        };
      },
    };
    return psuedoApp;
  };
}

export default function(context: Context, req: HttpRequest): void {
  AzureHttpAdapter.handle(createPsuedoApp(createApp), context, req);
}
```

It worked for me.

just update `/main/index.ts`

Comment: This somehow keeps the Location header, but loses the 302 status code making it 200.